# Flash cards for ARSnova system

Tags: r, r-exams

I recently discovered the Audience Response System [ARSnova](https://arsnova.eu) and you can use the r package exams to export quizzes to this platform. Since this platform also has flashcards, I want to know if there is a way to export flashcards to ARSnova from R. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Currently, this is not supported in R/exams.

Longer answer: At the moment R/exams supports the following exercise types: single-choice (schoice), multiple-choice (mchoice), numeric (num), string, cloze (= combinations of the others). None of these are obvious candidates for mapping to ARSnova flashcards.

I guess you could use one of them (probably string?) along with some custom options and transform it into the JSON for flashcards. This might be a bit technical but probably not a lot of code. In case you do play around with this, let us know.